# perl: function that gives nonzero integers between 1 and $input

Tags: perl

Im looking for (how to make?) a function (module?) that for

```
 my $scalar = 16;
 return function ($scalar);
```

gives

```
 @return = ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 );
```

That is, gives the non-zero integers between 1 and $scalar.

It's ok to assume $scalar is a big number, but im not particularly searching for a super optimal solution.

Comment: ``@return = [ 1, 2, ..., 16 ];`` doesn't make much sense. It should either be ``@return = ( 1, 2, ..., 16 );`` or ``$return = [ 1, 2, ..., 16];``. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you want all integers between `1` and `1_000_000_000`? You wouldn't want to create an array that big even if your computer has enough memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub make_lazy_increasing_sequence {
    my ($current, $end) = map int, @_;
    return sub {
        return if $current > $end;
        return $current++;
    }
}

my $from_1_to_5 = make_lazy_increasing_sequence(1, 5);
my @others;

while (defined(my $i = $from_1_to_5->())) {
    push @others, make_lazy_increasing_sequence($i, 10_000);
}

for (1 .. 10) { # perl makes sure this range is lazy
    print join(',', map $_->(), @others), "\n";
}

print $others[-1]->(), "\n";
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5
2,3,4,5,6
3,4,5,6,7
4,5,6,7,8
5,6,7,8,9
6,7,8,9,10
7,8,9,10,11
8,9,10,11,12
9,10,11,12,13
10,11,12,13,14
15
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Range Operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) `..` returns a list which matches exactly what you want.

To create a list from 1 to `$x`, the syntax is just `1 .. $x`

To assign that to an array variable, `@array = 1 .. $x;`

Answer (score 3):

`[1..16]`
creates an array reference

`1..16` creates a list.

Try this source

```
use Data::Dumper;
$c = [1..16];
@d = 1..16;
print Dumper $c;
print Dumper \@d;
```

Comment: The OP has changed his answer and removed the array ref. You should update your answer to reflect this, or it looks like you are the one suggesting it.

Comment: @TLP oh! I change my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
sub getvalue {
        my @array1 = 1..$_[0];

        return (@array1);
    }
```

else

```
sub getvalue {
            return ( 1..$_[0]); 
        }
```

refer this too know more about range operator

http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=377450

Comment: Why not just `return 1 .. $_[0]` ?

Comment: You could make this more robust with error checking on the input too. And I think the OP wants an array reference.

Comment: @friedo  fine we can do like that too , thanks for your comment

Comment: At its simplest, this can be put `sub getval { 1 .. shift }` Although I am dubious to the principle of making a subroutine out of an operator.